# R check error: no visible global function definition for a function that is defined within the package

Tags: r, namespaces, r-package, roxygen2, package-development

I am developing a package in R. When I run R checks, I get the following note:

> "reefSteady: no visible global function definition for 'tuneUR'"

Both `reefSteady()` and `tuneUR()` are functions that are defined within the package.

`tuneUR()` is exported and included in the NAMESPACE file. All documentation is being automatically generated by `roxygen2`. I have tried manually editing the NAMESPACE file to move `export(tuneUR)` above `export(reefSteady)` I but still get the note. I am using RStudio.

Not sure how to make it pass checks!

Comment: Can you give a link to the repo? Without seeing source, there's very little to comment on

Comment: Sure the repo is stored at https://github.com/cmbeese/mizerReef t's still in development

Comment: I don't have the `mizer*` packages installed, so I cannot run my own test, but I agree that it looks like it should work. Try forcing the order of files in your roxygen2 with something like https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/collate.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix it. @include reef-components.R did not ensure that all of the functions in reef-components.R were exported before `reef_steady`. But even if it had, I just tried changing the name of `tuneUR` to `atuneUR` just to see if the alphabetical order was the issue. I confirmed when I generated the NAMESPACE file that it was exported before `reef_steady`. But when I ran R checks I still got the note. :(

Comment: Hello, I still need help with this this if anyone is out there!